# Understanding how to emit processor instructions manually

Tags: c++, linux, assembly

I was reading an article about how to construct a  [Jit Compiler](http://blog.reverberate.org/2012/12/hello-jit-world-joy-of-simple-jits.html), and the author essentially uses this code:

```
// Processor instructions for:
//   mov eax, 0   
//   ret 
unsigned char code[] = {0xb8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc3};

void *mem = mmap(NULL, sizeof(code), PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC,
    MAP_ANON | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);  

memcpy(mem, code, sizeof(code));

int (*func)() = mem;   
return func();
```

I get everything about the code except for how he knew how to manually map the assembler instructions to numerical codes. What do I need to study in order to understant that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the article author, hope you enjoyed it!

To construct those values, I basically did

```
$ cat test.S
  .intel_syntax noprefix
  mov eax, 0
  ret
$ gcc -c -o test.o test.S
$ objdump -d -M intel test.o

test.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
   5:   c3                      ret
```

You can see the bytes for the instructions in the left column.  I don't recommend studying the instruction encodings too deeply unless you have a really good reason.  They're pretty complicated, and assemblers are really good at generating this stuff.  There are tons of other things to learn at this level that will make better use of your brain energy.  Read [Agner Fog's manuals](http://www.agner.org/optimize/) for a great start.

Comment: So I've been experimenting with this enough to grok how it all works and how to emit my own code (awesome, awesome article) etc. One thing I have a question on, in the article you mention that `we want to avoid mapping any memory both writable and executable`. I guess I'm wondering from a high level: (1) what are the risks, (2) how do you set this up properly then? Thanks again, and love your articles!

Comment: @sircodesalot: the risk is that someone who manages to exploit a buffer overflow can write their own executable instructions to that memory and then jump there.  Basically it's another vector for attack.  The way to avoid it is to first map the memory rw, then change the mapping to rx as I do in this code: https://github.com/haberman/jitdemo/blob/master/dynasm-driver.c#L45

Comment: Glad you enjoyed the article!

Answer (score 4):

There are references ([such as these for Intel 64 and IA-32](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)) which cover how the assembly instructions map onto the actual machine-code. This will of course between CPUs/environments - e.g. the above won't work on ARM systems.

Alternatively, the values might be copied from existing generated output such as from the output of an assembler.

Comment: That got me moving in the right direction. I found a listing here: http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html. The only thing I don't understand is how MOV (0xB8) seems to be the start of the first instruction, while it appears to be at the end of the second (RET:0xC3).

Comment: @sircodesalot Different instructions like `mov` have different modes (e.g. immediate? register? memory?) and take different parameters (i.e. `eax`, `0`). On the other hand, there is only one simple argument-less form of `ret`, which is why it seems so small (a single byte) in comparison to the `mov` output which has to encode all the other data as well.

Comment: I guess I need to get back to studying computer architecture. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use many libraries for coding a JIT. [AsmJit](http://code.google.com/p/asmjit/) will help you emit machine code instructions (on x86). [GNU lightning](http://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/), [libjit](http://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/), [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) will translate some abstract instruction set (or abstract syntax tree) into machine code.

Processors [Instruction Set Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set) are documented (in long boring documents). For [x86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) you may need to read thousand of pages.